# d3.js bar matrix - reset height if different column

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The task is to create a "matrix bar chart" that shows absolute values in terms of y axis, but also color codes to show qualitative dimensions. In this simple case, the qualitative dimension will be either `bond` or `equity`. Example data:

```
var data = [
    {'type':'equity','date':'t1'},
    {'type':'equity','date':'t1'},
    {'type':'equity','date':'t1'},
    {'type':'equity','date':'t1'},
    {'type':'equity','date':'t1'},
    {'type':'equity','date':'t1'},
    {'type':'equity','date':'t1'},
    {'type':'equity','date':'t1'},
    {'type':'equity','date':'t1'},
    {'type':'equity','date':'t1'},
    {'type':'bond','date':'t1'},
    {'type':'bond','date':'t1'},
    {'type':'bond','date':'t1'},
...
];
```

I have used a grid-like anchoring framework to append `g`'s to achieve the matrix part of the visual.

```
var anchorG = graphGroup.selectAll('.anchorG')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'anchor')
  .attr('id', (d, i) => 'anchor' + i)
  .attr('transform', (d, k) => {
    var horSpace = (k % columns) * spacing;
    var vertSpace = ~~((k / columns)) * vSpacing;
    return "translate(" + (-horSpace) + "," + (-vertSpace) + ")";
  });
```

In the below snippet, we will see that the desired effect is recognizable:

```js
var margins = {top:100, bottom:300, left:100, right:100};

var height = 600;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
.append('svg')
.attr('width', totalWidth)
.attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
.attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

var data = [
{'type':'equity','date':'t1'},
{'type':'equity','date':'t1'},
{'type':'equity','date':'t1'},
{'type':'equity','date':'t1'},
{'type':'equity','date':'t1'},
{'type':'equity','date':'t1'},
{'type':'equity','date':'t1'},
{'type':'equity','date':'t1'},
{'type':'equity','date':'t1'},
{'type':'equity','date':'t1'},
{'type':'bond','date':'t1'},
{'type':'bond','date':'t1'},
{'type':'bond','date':'t1'},
{'type':'bond','date':'t1'},
{'type':'bond','date':'t1'},
{'type':'bond','date':'t1'},
{'type':'bond','date':'t1'},
{'type':'bond','date':'t1'},
{'type':'bond','date':'t1'},
{'type':'bond','date':'t1'},
{'type':'bond','date':'t1'},
{'type':'bond','date':'t1'},
{'type':'bond','date':'t1'},
{'type':'bond','date':'t1'},
{'type':'bond','date':'t1'},
{'type':'bond','date':'t1'},
{'type':'bond','date':'t1'},
{'type':'bond','date':'t1'},
{'type':'bond','date':'t1'},
{'type':'bond','date':'t1'},
{'type':'equity','date':'t2'},
{'type':'equity','date':'t2'},
{'type':'equity','date':'t2'},
{'type':'equity','date':'t2'},
{'type':'equity','date':'t2'},
{'type':'equity','date':'t2'},
{'type':'equity','date':'t2'},
{'type':'equity','date':'t2'},
{'type':'equity','date':'t2'},
{'type':'equity','date':'t2'},
{'type':'equity','date':'t2'},
{'type':'equity','date':'t2'},
{'type':'equity','date':'t2'},
{'type':'equity','date':'t2'},
{'type':'equity','date':'t2'},
{'type':'equity','date':'t2'},
{'type':'equity','date':'t2'},
{'type':'equity','date':'t2'},
{'type':'equity','date':'t2'},
{'type':'equity','date':'t2'},
{'type':'bond','date':'t2'},
{'type':'bond','date':'t2'},
{'type':'bond','date':'t2'},
{'type':'bond','date':'t2'},
{'type':'bond','date':'t2'},
{'type':'bond','date':'t2'},
{'type':'bond','date':'t2'},
{'type':'bond','date':'t2'},
{'type':'bond','date':'t2'},
];

var columns = 5;
var spacing = 10;
var vSpacing = 10;

var anchorG = graphGroup.selectAll('.anchorG')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'anchor')
  .attr('id', (d, i) => 'anchor' + i)
  .attr('transform', (d, k) => {
var horSpace = (k % columns) * spacing;
var vertSpace = ~~((k / columns)) * vSpacing;
return "translate(" + (-horSpace) + "," + (-vertSpace) + ")";
  });

var xScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
.range([0,100,200,300,400,500,600,700])
.domain(['t0','t1','t2','t3','t4','t5','t6','t7',]);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
.range([308,0])
.domain([0,160]);

graphGroup.append('g')
  .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale))
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 310)');

graphGroup.append('g')
  .call(d3.axisRight(yScale))
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 0)')
  .selectAll('text')
  .attr('text-anchor','end')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(-15, 0)');

var colorMap = {
  'equity':'#003366',
  'bond':'#4f81b9'
};

anchorG.append('rect')
.attr('x', function(d) {return xScale(d.date)+16})
.attr('y', function(d,i) {return 300})
.attr('width', 8)
.attr('height', 8)
.style('fill', function(d) {return colorMap[d.type]});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

However, we can also see there is a flaw in the `y` logic. The second column starts where the first column left off. For this visual to succeed, the second column will need to assume the original starting point. Herein lies the dilemma: if we modify the original `y` position, we lose the ability to stack with the ease of our grid framework.

I have attempted to find a work-around by resetting `y` if the current datum is not equal to the previous datum:

```
.attr('y', function(d,i) {return data[i].date != data[i-1].date ? 300 : 500})
```

But this returned:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'date' of undefined.

This mystifies me since I hardcoded the data for every item in the array of `data`.

### Question

How can I coordinate between my existing grid system and the need for resetting the starting points for subsequent columns of rects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I suggest that you use a different approach not because of your original problem but because you have a `<rect>` inside a `<g>` for each one of these data points! That's a lot of unnecessary elements.

So, in my solution, we'll create a single `<g>` elements for each `type`, based on a nested data:

```
const nested = d3.nest()
  .key(d => d.date)
  .entries(data);

var anchorG = graphGroup.selectAll('.anchorG')
  .data(nested)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'anchor')
  .attr('id', (d, i) => 'anchor' + i)
  .attr('transform', d => "translate(" + (xScale(d.key) - (columns * spacing) / 2) + "," + (height - margins.bottom) + ")");
```

Then, we append the rectangles to each individual `<g>`:

```
const rects = anchorG.selectAll(null)
  .data(d => d.values)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr('x', (_, i) => (i % columns) * spacing)
  .attr('y', (_, i) => -(~~((i / columns)) * vSpacing))
  .attr('width', 8)
  .attr('height', 8)
  .style('fill', function(d) {
    return colorMap[d.type]
  });
```

That way we fix that huge amount of unnecessary elements and, as a side effect, we end up fixing your original problem as well.

Here is your code with that change:

```js
var margins = {
  top: 100,
  bottom: 300,
  left: 100,
  right: 100
};

var height = 600;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width + margins.left + margins.right;
var totalHeight = height + margins.top + margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', totalWidth)
  .attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', "translate(" + margins.left + "," + margins.top + ")");

var data = [{
    'type': 'equity',
    'date': 't1'
  },
  {
    'type': 'equity',
    'date': 't1'
  },
  {
    'type': 'equity',
    'date': 't1'
  },
  {
    'type': 'equity',
    'date': 't1'
  },
  {
    'type': 'equity',
    'date': 't1'
  },
  {
    'type': 'equity',
    'date': 't1'
  },
  {
    'type': 'equity',
    'date': 't1'
  },
  {
    'type': 'equity',
    'date': 't1'
  },
  {
    'type': 'equity',
    'date': 't1'
  },
  {
    'type': 'equity',
    'date': 't1'
  },
  {
    'type': 'bond',
    'date': 't1'
  },
  {
    'type': 'bond',
    'date': 't1'
  },
  {
    'type': 'bond',
    'date': 't1'
  },
  {
    'type': 'bond',
    'date': 't1'
  },
  {
    'type': 'bond',
    'date': 't1'
  },
  {
    'type': 'bond',
    'date': 't1'
  },
  {
    'type': 'bond',
    'date': 't1'
  },
  {
    'type': 'bond',
    'date': 't1'
  },
  {
    'type': 'bond',
    'date': 't1'
  },
  {
    'type': 'bond',
    'date': 't1'
  },
  {
    'type': 'bond',
    'date': 't1'
  },
  {
    'type': 'bond',
    'date': 't1'
  },
  {
    'type': 'bond',
    'date': 't1'
  },
  {
    'type': 'bond',
    'date': 't1'
  },
  {
    'type': 'bond',
    'date': 't1'
  },
  {
    'type': 'bond',
    'date': 't1'
  },
  {
    'type': 'bond',
    'date': 't1'
  },
  {
    'type': 'bond',
    'date': 't1'
  },
  {
    'type': 'bond',
    'date': 't1'
  },
  {
    'type': 'bond',
    'date': 't1'
  },
  {
    'type': 'equity',
    'date': 't2'
  },
  {
    'type': 'equity',
    'date': 't2'
  },
  {
    'type': 'equity',
    'date': 't2'
  },
  {
    'type': 'equity',
    'date': 't2'
  },
  {
    'type': 'equity',
    'date': 't2'
  },
  {
    'type': 'equity',
    'date': 't2'
  },
  {
    'type': 'equity',
    'date': 't2'
  },
  {
    'type': 'equity',
    'date': 't2'
  },
  {
    'type': 'equity',
    'date': 't2'
  },
  {
    'type': 'equity',
    'date': 't2'
  },
  {
    'type': 'equity',
    'date': 't2'
  },
  {
    'type': 'equity',
    'date': 't2'
  },
  {
    'type': 'equity',
    'date': 't2'
  },
  {
    'type': 'equity',
    'date': 't2'
  },
  {
    'type': 'equity',
    'date': 't2'
  },
  {
    'type': 'equity',
    'date': 't2'
  },
  {
    'type': 'equity',
    'date': 't2'
  },
  {
    'type': 'equity',
    'date': 't2'
  },
  {
    'type': 'equity',
    'date': 't2'
  },
  {
    'type': 'equity',
    'date': 't2'
  },
  {
    'type': 'bond',
    'date': 't2'
  },
  {
    'type': 'bond',
    'date': 't2'
  },
  {
    'type': 'bond',
    'date': 't2'
  },
  {
    'type': 'bond',
    'date': 't2'
  },
  {
    'type': 'bond',
    'date': 't2'
  },
  {
    'type': 'bond',
    'date': 't2'
  },
  {
    'type': 'bond',
    'date': 't2'
  },
  {
    'type': 'bond',
    'date': 't2'
  },
  {
    'type': 'bond',
    'date': 't2'
  },
];

var xScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range([0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700])
  .domain(['t0', 't1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5', 't6', 't7']);

var colorMap = {
  'equity': '#003366',
  'bond': '#4f81b9'
};

const nested = d3.nest()
  .key(d => d.date)
  .entries(data);

var columns = 5;
var spacing = 10;
var vSpacing = 10;

var anchorG = graphGroup.selectAll('.anchorG')
  .data(nested)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'anchor')
  .attr('id', (d, i) => 'anchor' + i)
  .attr('transform', d => "translate(" + (xScale(d.key) - (columns * spacing) / 2) + "," + (height - margins.bottom) + ")");

const rects = anchorG.selectAll(null)
  .data(d => d.values)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr('x', (_, i) => (i % columns) * spacing)
  .attr('y', (_, i) => -(~~((i / columns)) * vSpacing))
  .attr('width', 8)
  .attr('height', 8)
  .style('fill', function(d) {
    return colorMap[d.type]
  });

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([308, 0])
  .domain([0, 160]);

graphGroup.append('g')
  .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale))
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 310)');

graphGroup.append('g')
  .call(d3.axisRight(yScale))
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 0)')
  .selectAll('text')
  .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(-15, 0)');
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```